# Find matching pairs and lay them out as columns in polars

Tags: python, python-polars

Say I have this:

```
df = polars.DataFrame(dict(
  j=numpy.random.randint(10, 99, 9),
  k=numpy.tile([1, 2, 2], 3),
  ))
  
 j (i64)  k (i64)
 47       1
 22       2
 82       2
 19       1
 85       2
 15       2
 89       1
 74       2
 26       2
shape: (9, 2)
```

where column `k` is kind of a marker - `1` starts and then there are one or more `2`s (in the above example always two for simplicity, but in practice one or more). I'd like to get values in `j` that correspond to `k=1` and the last corresponding `k=2`. For the above:

```
 j (i64)  k (i64)
 47       1 >-\
 22       2   | these are the 1 and the last of its matching 2s
 82       2 <-/
 19       1 >-\
 85       2   | these are the 1 and the last of its matching 2s
 15       2 <-/
 89       1 >-\
 74       2   | these are the 1 and the last of its matching 2s
 26       2 <-/
shape: (9, 2)
```

and I'd like to put these in two columns, so I get this:

```
 j (i64)  k (i64)
 47       82
 19       15
 89       26
shape: (9, 2)
```

How would I approach this in polars?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `filter` simply by looking for `k=1` or when the next `k`, e.g. a [`shift`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.shift.html#polars.Expr.shift), is `1`:

```py
df.select(
    j=pl.col('j').filter(pl.col('k') == 1),
    k=pl.col('j').filter(pl.col('k').shift(-1).fill_null(1) == 1),
)
```

```py
shape: (3, 2)
┌─────┬─────┐
│ j   ┆ k   │
│ --- ┆ --- │
│ i32 ┆ i32 │
╞═════╪═════╡
│ 47  ┆ 82  │
│ 19  ┆ 15  │
│ 89  ┆ 26  │
└─────┴─────┘
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import polars
import numpy

def construct_example(seed, n):
    numpy.random.seed(seed)
    ks = []
    js = []
    expected_res = []
    for i in range(n):
        ntwos = numpy.random.randint(1, 4)
        ks.extend([1] + [2 for j in range(ntwos)])
        ijs = numpy.random.randint(10, 99, ntwos + 1)
        js.extend(list(ijs))
        expected_res.append((ijs[0], ijs[-1]))
    df = polars.DataFrame(dict(j=js, k=ks))
    return df, expected_res

def solve(df):
    jarr = list(df['j']) + [None]
    karr = list(df['k']) + [1]
    res = []
    for i, (j, k) in enumerate(zip(jarr, karr)):
        if k == 1 and j is not None:
            res.append((j, jarr[i+karr[i+1:].index(1)]))
    return res

df, expected_res = construct_example(42, 10)

assert solve(df) == expected_res

print(list(df.iter_rows()))
print(expected_res)
```

prints

```
[(61, 1), (24, 2), (81, 2), (70, 2), (92, 1), (96, 2), (84, 1), (97, 2), (33, 2), (12, 2), (62, 1), (11, 2), (97, 2), (47, 1), (11, 2), (73, 2), (42, 1), (85, 2), (31, 1), (98, 2), (58, 2), (68, 1), (51, 2), (69, 2), (89, 2), (71, 1), (71, 2), (56, 2), (71, 2), (64, 1), (73, 2), (12, 2), (60, 2)]
[(61, 70), (92, 96), (84, 12), (62, 97), (47, 73), (42, 85), (31, 58), (68, 89), (71, 71), (64, 60)]
```

Explanation:

The function `construct_example` creates example data for `n` row groups, where the number of 2's per row groups can vary, and returns the corresponding `polars.DataFrame` and the expected pairs `expected_res` (as a list of tuples).

The function `solve` takes any such dataframe (assuming it satisfies the conditions of having only the said two markers, no two consective 1's and ending in a 2) and computes the matches as follows:

Add an extra row with `k=1` and `j=None`, then iterate through the rows (indexed by `i`) and whenever you encounter a `k=1` and corresponding `j` that is not `None`, take the `j` as the first element and then find the index of the next `1` (equal to `i+1` plus the index of the first `1` when considering only values below/after), hence the corresponding `j` for the second element must sit at index `i+karr[i+1:].index(1)`.